# Lickly hood estimators and discrete random var

Tags: probability, statistics

If have discrete random variable X and have the observations that X=1, twice, X=3, once and X=4, six times is the likely hood of these observations, L = P(X=1)^2 . P(X=3)^1 . P(X=4)^6 or L = ((2+1+6)!/(2!.1!.6!)) P(X=1)^2 . P(X=3)^1 . P(X=4)^6. I ask because I have seen both and am confused? Please your answer, thanks.

Comment: Second one. Where have you seen both?

Comment: The class of estimators with the property of being 'from the hood' are prime. The lickly ones have maximum variance and should be avoided.

Comment: I have seen the second in my textbooks, but the first in practice exam papers. Do we ever use the first one?

Comment: It is the first question on this exam paper that the first one appears http://www.mei.org.uk/files/papers/s409ju_7ik7.pdf

Answer (score 0):

If we observe an independent sample $y_1, y_2, ... ,y_n$ from a distribution $f(y|θ)$, the likelihood is L($\theta$) = $\prod_{i=1}^n f(y_i|θ)$ , where conditioning on the sample $y_1, ..., y_n$ is understood. \
From this definition, it is evident that the first one, i.e. $L = P(X=1)^2 . P(X=3)^1 . P(X=4)^6$ is not your likelihood and the second one is, unless you are willing to consider the order of your sample observations(why would you?). \

[P.S.- However, note that the coefficient(a constant, $\gt 1$) in the second formula simply vanishes when the derivative is taken for log likelihood, so it would not matter at all when finding the 'critical' value.]

Comment: "From this definition, it is evident that the first one ... is your likelihood, unless you are willing to consider the order of your sample observations" Actually it is obvious that the first one is the likelihood **IF** one considers the order of the sample observations, that is, if the results were exactly 113444444 in this order.

Comment: Yup, that's what I meant, so had to correct it. Thanks @Did.